# Django ImageField remove path on Bound form

Tags: django, django-models, boundfield

So I have a ModelForm which is using an ImageField, which works as expected for both inserts and updates. I also have a widget implemented to display a thumbnail for the image if the form is bound. The issue I am having is the file path is still being displayed (along with the thumbnail). How can I override this URL such that it is not rendered as well as the label "Currently"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attributes responsible for rendering the current file path to an instantiated form us found in: `forms.widgets.ClearableFileInput()`

Override ClearableFileInput()'s render method. 
In my case I changed

```
substitutions['initial'] = (u'<a href="%s">%s</a>'
                                    % (escape(value.url),
                                       escape(force_unicode(value))))
```

to

```
substitutions['initial'] = (u'%s <br />'
                                %(escape(force_unicode(os.path.basename(value.url)))))
```

Doing this removed the path to the current file and displays just the file name, without a link.